# The sentence grammar for "I wanted to gorge myself, gorge I did."

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-usage

One of my friends who is a native speaker once said the sentence:

> I wanted to gorge myself, gorge I did.

I may not remember what's the exact sentence he said, but the sentence structure should be similar.

The part I am curious most is **gorge I did**. The word **gorge** is a verb. How come the clause **I did** could modify a verb? What's the grammar behind? I rarely see this kind of the sentence structure, and if it's correct, under what circumstances it should be used? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this structure is designed to put an emphasis on the fact that he gorged. It's not super standard to word it the way he did, but he did it for special effect.  Gorge, however, isn't the main verb. If you reorder the word that becomes apparent.

> I did gorge.

So really it's not modifying or doing anything, it's simply a "helping verb" of types.